# Can't compile document that uses PGFPlots from cmd

Tags: pgfplots, windows, gnuplot

When I try to compile [this code example](http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/gnuplot-basics/) from Command Prompt (cmd) in Windows 10, with MiKTeX and with the following command:

```
pdflatex.exe -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode -shell-escape pgfplotstest.tex
```

pdflatex fails to compile the complete example and only gived me a pdf with the grid, the axis and the labels but not with the [actual plots](https://ci.memecdn.com/4613147.jpg). In the log file, I'm getting the following warnings:

```
runsystem(gnuplot pgfplotstest.x.gnuplot)...executed.



Package pgf Warning: Plot data file `pgfplotstest.x.table' not found. on input 
line 17.

\openout3 = `pgfplotstest.sin.gnuplot'.

runsystem(gnuplot pgfplotstest.sin.gnuplot)...executed.


Package pgf Warning: Plot data file `pgfplotstest.sin.table' not found. on inpu
t line 19.

\openout3 = `pgfplotstest.exp.gnuplot'.

runsystem(gnuplot pgfplotstest.exp.gnuplot)...executed.


Package pgf Warning: Plot data file `pgfplotstest.exp.table' not found. on inpu
t line 21.
```

but I'm not getting any errors. The following files are generated:

```
pgfplotstest.aux
pgfplotstest.exp.gnuplot
pgfplotstest.log
pgfplotstest.pdf
pgfplotstest.sin.gnuplot
pgfplotstest.synctex.gz
pgfplotstest.x.gnuplot
```

Gnuplot is installed and added to my `PATH`, and the document compiles fine in Git Bash using the same command. Why does it fail to compile in cmd?

Answer (score 2):

I turned out that the Windows installer for Gnuplot [adds an extra "`;`" in `PATH`](https://sourceforge.net/p/gnuplot/bugs/1990/) if you check the checkbox to add Gnuplot to path, resulting in the path to Gnuplot being preceded by not one but *two* semicolons in `PATH`, which probably made cmd unable to recognize `gnuplot` as an executable.

Removing the extra semicolon (by going to "System Properties->Environment Variables...", clicking `Path` under System variables, then "Edit...->Edit text...") and restarting cmd resolved the problem.